# AMP analytics - how to track "click" and "visible" elements from an amp-list

Tags: amp-html

I know how to set a basic click tracking inside the amp-analytics tag. But is it possible to bind a click tracking on a dynamic item inside an `<amp-list>`?

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackClickOnMyDynamicItem" : {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "#myElementInAmpList",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "someCategory",
        "eventAction": "someAction",
        "eventLabel": "someDynamicLabelRetrievedFromAmpList"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using data-vars-*
for example:

```
<amp-list>
<template type="amp-mustache">
<a href="{{ Url }}" id="myElementInAmpList"  data-vars-product-name ="{{ ProductName }}">
</template>
</amp-list>
```

in the tracking script you can have :

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json"> {"vars": {
"account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"},
"triggers": {
 "trackClickOnMyDynamicItem" : {
  "on": "click",
  "selector": "#myElementInAmpList",
  "request": "event",
  "vars": {"eventCategory": "someCategory",
    "eventAction": "someAction",
    "eventLabel": "${productName}" //this will be dynamic 
         }
       }
     }
   }
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

[refer the documentation here in the last part of the page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md#variables-as-data-attribute)

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. Any suggestion on how to send the same data-vars-* when the element is loaded/visible?

Comment: it's very simple in the triggers just change 
"on" : "click" to "on" : "visible"

Comment: Tried that, and it just won't fire. I don't really know how the events are attached to the elements. But "visible" on a dynamic element from an amp-list does not work.

Comment: i am not sure, but i think it wont work. for other examples do check this out. 
[link](https://github.com/ampproject/ampstart/blob/f7c66e8757c90b61ed91de0c32c4190123dd8f4a/utils/www-analytics.snip.html#L25)

Comment: @JayeshBafna Did you get any other solution to track visible events for amp list items ?

Comment: @MikinjMistry I used a combination of this answer above, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827120/amp-list-element-analytics

but as you can see, the answers are really old, I have not worked with AMP in the recent years so there might be simpler more elegant solutions out there.

You just have to change "on": "click", to "on": "visible"